# How to undo TRUNCATE command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I accidently executed TRUNCATE command on a wrong table and all my data is gone. We do have a backup but its 2 weeks old and doesn’t have all the latest data.

Any ideas how can we rollback this command and get the data back if possible? Are there any third party tools that can do this?

Comment: What recovery model is the database in? Assuming that you can't do a point of time recovery to before the `TRUNCATE` command then in principle the data might be recoverable as `TRUNCATE` just deallocates the pages leaving the data intact but I'm not aware of any third party tools that do this.

Comment: If the database is in full mode and the log hasn't been truncated for any reason, you could try backing up the transaction log now and then restoring the DB to a point in time just before the truncate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is – you can’t rollback a transaction if it’s already committed but you can do something else to get the data back (or at least some parts of it).

When you execute truncate statement your data is still in the MDF file but it’s not visible because SQL Server is now treating this as free space (truncate is basically telling SQL Server to deallocate data pages).

Only way to get the data back is to somehow read deallocated data pages and convert them into readable data.

Important: you must act fast because free space will be overwritten with new data if not already. If you can stop your SQL Server instance and make a copy of MDF and LDF files that would buy you more time.

Try using [ApexSQL Recover](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_recover.aspx). From what I know it’s the only available tool that can do this kind of restore. If you’re really good with SQL you can try modifying and executing very long script like [this](http://raresql.com/2012/04/08/how-to-recover-truncated-data-from-sql-server-without-backup/) .

Answer (score 0):

Unless it was Transaction Wrapped, I am afraid you are out of luck.
Here is a similar post, but this also has more explanations.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/how-to-rollback-truncate-operation.16968/

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link. Imagine that page is moved to another server, or the direct link changes - future users will not be able to benefit from the answer. Please take a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).